# How to convert Uint8List to C equivalent datatype using dart:ffi

Tags: c++, opencv, flutter, dart-ffi

I am trying to send an image to my Custom C++ code which I am planning to run using dart:ffi. I have successfully run the hello world problem where I send two integers and get the some of them as another intiger.

Now I want to send a whole image to it and process it on my C++ code. I am able to get `Uint8List` from the `CameraImage` using the below code

```
Future<ui.Image> convertCameraImageToUiImage(CameraImage image) async {
imglib.Image libImage = imglib.Image.fromBytes(
  image.width,
  image.height,
  image.planes[0].bytes,
  format: imglib.Format.bgra,
);
final c = Completer<ui.Image>();
ui.decodeImageFromPixels(
  libImage.getBytes(),
  image.width,
  image.height,
  ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888,
  c.complete,
);
return c.future;
```

}

Then I converted it to `Uint8List`

```
ByteData data = await image.toByteData();
Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
```

My problem is, how should I define lookup function to send a `Uint8List` to the C++ code and get `List<bool>`, my function over C++ expects `cv::mat` (I can tweak it to receive array of integers) as a parameter and sends a Vector of boolean.

This is what I have tried

```
final List<bool> Function(Uint8List image) _imageToCode = nativeAddLib
.lookup<NativeFunction<List<bool> Function(List<Uint8List>)>>("imageToCode")
.asFunction();
```

The problem is, the bool and Uint8List are not a type supported by C++ so the function doesn't recognize them. How should I send it over the channel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to allocate, and then copy the data into, a `Pointer<something>`. Your exported C function can then have a `something*` argument. You will also need to pass the length of the data. As the goal is to construct a `cv::Mat` you might want to pass the geometry instead, and infer the data length from that.

So, if your exported C function has a signature:

```
void process(int32_t width, int32_t height, uint8_t *bytes);
```

your two Dart typedefs would be:

```
typedef process_func = Void Function(Int32 width, Int32 height, Pointer<Uint8> bytes);
typedef ProcessFunc = void Function(int width, int height, Pointer<Uint8> bytes);
```

use those in the lookup

```
_process = nativeLib
    .lookup<NativeFunction<process_func>>('process')
    .asFunction();
```

To allocate the buffer, first `import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';` and use `allocate`

```
var outBuf = allocate<Uint8>(count: outSize);
```

then use a for loop to copy the data. Alternatively use `asTypedData` on `outBuf` to get a `Uint8List` and use `setAll`.

Remember to `free` the buffer after using it.

(As your pixels are rgba8888, they fit in unsigned 32 bit ints. You might want to pass `Uint32`s across in your pointer, and get them using `data.buffer.asUint32List()`.)

You want to return a list of `bool`. `bool` isn't supported you you have to pass a list of, say, `Int8` where you've set the values to 1 and 0 respectively. (If your list is bounded and reasonably sized, you could use a bitmap. For example, if you knew it was always 32 bits long, pack those bits into a Uint32 as 32 ones and zeroes.)

There are a couple of strategies for returning a list, where list in `ffi` is going to mean `Pointer<something>` of course.

If the list is bounded, you can allocate it on the Dart side, pass the pointer with the function and have the C function fill in the values, maybe returning an integer of the number it filled in.

If the list is unbounded you must allow C to `malloc` it, as only the C function knows how much space it needs. You now need to return 2 values: the pointer and the length. Since you can only return one value you need to do something like pass in a `Pointer<Int32>` and have the C function assign the length to that.

Comment: I haven't dived into how `package:ffi` looked when this answer was written, but I currently I think you'd need to use `malloc.allocate(outSize)` (and matched with `malloc.free`).