# Is there a way to send a dart array to C without copying the array?

Tags: c, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I am using dart:ffi.

I have a C function that accepts a pointer to array:

```c
void myCFunc(const void *pointer);
```

I want to call it from dart, right now, I am calling it like this:

```dart
void myDartFunc(Uint8List data) {
  final Pointer<UnsignedChar> dataPtr = malloc(
    sizeOf<UnsignedChar>() * (data.length),
  );
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataPtr[i] = data[i];
  }
  callMyCFunc(dataPtr);
}
```

Which is not so optimal for long lists as it copies the array into a new array.

Is there a way to get pointer to `data` without copying each element?

Comment: Maybe: [How to convert Uint8List to C equivalent datatype using dart:ffi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62102889/5382650)

Comment: @CraigEstey I think that answer suggests allocating memory then copying the array into it, which is what I want to avoid

Comment: No, there's no way to avoid it. If you have a `Pointer` you can turn it into a typed list using `asTypedList` and then use `setAll` to (presumably) efficiently copy from/to another typed list.